# Porting a Java 8 application to Java 11

Tags: java, java-8, arduino-ide, java-11

I have been trying to port a Java 8 desktop application to Java 11. I have a high level idea of how Java 9 and after are different from Java 8. eg: support for modularization, JDK is modular, no separate JRE.

Overall it is my understanding that the process of porting to Java 11 consists of the following steps:

1. Find out what dependencies are going out of support in Java 9 or later. We use `jdeps -jdkinternals` tool found in Java 8 jdk for this.
2. The dependencies found in `Step 1` may be handled in two ways:
   **a.**  If the dependency package is still there in Java 9 or later, but is just encapsulated, then use --add-exports command to make the JDK export those packages.
   **b.** If the dependency package has been removed from Java, I will have to change the application's code to use a replacement package. `jdeps` tool will give me the replacement package to use.
3. Once the issue of unsupported dependencies has been resolved, we use `jdeps --list-deps` on all the jars (both generated by our program and used by our program) to get to know about the packages of JDK to include in runtime.
4. Once the dependencies are listed, we provide `jlink` of Java 11 to build a runtime for the application.

Am I correct in understanding this process? What are the surprises I might face?

---

UPDATE:

The comments below say that a custom runtime using jlink may not be required. However, we had problems using normal Java 8 runtime. Posting details below for more context.

The project we have been trying to port is [Arduino](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino) and are using Mac OS to do that. Arduino uses `Ant` to build. The `build.xml` is [here](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/build/build.xml). What we initially did is change JAVA_HOME to point to Java 11 and use ant dist to compile it. For some reason, the application doesn't compile on Java 11 till you remove ../ at the end of line 69 in build.xml. After this the application compiled and provided an executable at the path given at line 512 of build.xml. But when we try to run the executable, it gives the error `Java Runtime` not found.

Comment: Do you have a reason to build a custom runtime? Its not strictly required you can still use the standard install like you did in Java 8.  Do you have a plan in place to distribute your custom JRE already?

Comment: @Deadron I thought we ought to make a custom runtime. How do we use the runtime of Java 8 with Java 11 ported app?

Comment: Now that I remember, I did try to use the Java 8 runtime. But when I ran the application (we used `ant run`), the app started, but gave an error `Java Runtime Engine not found`

Comment: This probably means your box is not setup properly for your ant script. The installation process has changed installation directories and environment variables. We would need to know the details of your ant script to help further.

Comment: @Deadron... sure. We have been trying to port Arduino project and are using Mac OS to do that. The `build.xml` is at https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/build/build.xml. What we initially did is change JAVA_HOME to point to Java 11 and use `ant dist` to compile it. For some reason, the application doesn't build on Java 11 till you remove `../` at the end of line 69 in `build.xml`. After this the application compiled and provided an executable at the path given at line 512 of `build.xml`. But when we try to run the executable, it gives the error `Java Runtime not found`

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not familiar with a build process like yours that produces an exe. It looks like you are not able to find the java runtime which begs the question how do you locate it in the first place?

Comment: I suspect that your issues stem from com.oracle.appbundler.AppBundlerTask but I have never personally used it. A brief google search suggests it may not be avaliable in OpenJDK builds and may not even be compatible with Java 11. We would need the actual source to be sure. I would suggest creating a new question specifically about this.

Comment: On the `jlink` step, there would be a blocker if you still have *automatic modules* on your *modulepath*. I would suggest you to detail out the migration process step by step and try solving one step at a time. There is a significant effort while you migrate that would be spend on understanding the changes that you might rely on your dependent libraries/frameworks as well. Just for e.g. Ant's support for Java11.